# bash: preserve white character when cutting in a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, cut

it looks like while read line discards the blank first characters

```
while read line; 
 do DB=$(  echo "$line" | cut -c1-8);           
 echo DB=$DB; 
 echo $line; 
done < histogram.txt
```

text

> ```
>       7107: ( 12,255,  0) #0CFF00 srgb(12,255,0)
>       4514: ( 12,255,255) #0CFFFF srgb(12,255,255)
>      11580: ( 30,  0,253) #1E00FD srgb(30,0,253)
>      14365: (246,255,  0) #F6FF00 srgb(246,255,0)
>      29576: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
> ____188858: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
> ```

expected result for line 1 "....7107" (. = space)
what I really get "7107: ( "

the last line works ("____1888") because I replaced space by underscore
result

SO how do I get the blank characters ?

Comment: Use: `IFS=` as: `while IFS= read -r line; do ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 things:

1. set IFS to a null string for the `read` command: `while IFS= read -r line` -- that will preserve all whitespace into the variable
2. quote the variable **everywhere** you use it: `echo "$line"`

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  DB="${line:1:8}"
  echo "DB=$DB"
  echo "$line"
done < histogram.txt
```

bash parameter substution can take a substring, so you don't need `cut`

Comment: Use `DB=${line%%:*}` or `IFS=: read -r DB _ <<< "$line"` to avoid having to specify the exact width of the field.